Associativity of Hecke Operators in Bump
I was looking through Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations and was thinking about his initial description of Hecke algebras. In short, for $\alpha \in \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})^+$, the double coset $\Gamma \alpha \Gamma$ (where I write $\Gamma = \Gamma(1) = \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$) is a finite union of right cosets
$$ \Gamma \alpha \Gamma = \bigcup \Gamma \alpha_i, \qquad (\alpha_i \in \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})^+).$$
We define the Hecke algebra $\mathcal{R}$ to be the free abelian group generated by symbols $T_\alpha$, as $\alpha$ runs through a complete set of representatives for $\Gamma \backslash \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})^+ / \Gamma$.
We define multiplication in $\mathcal{R}$ by
$$ T_\alpha \cdot T_\beta = \sum_{\sigma} m(\alpha, \beta; \sigma) T_\sigma, $$
where $m(\alpha, \beta; \sigma)$ is the cardinality of the set of indices $(i, j)$ such that $\sigma \in \Gamma(1) \alpha_i \beta_j$.
(I have implicitly written $\Gamma \beta \Gamma = \bigcup \Gamma \beta_j$).
Bump them claims that one can show this is associative by noting (with $\Gamma \gamma \Gamma = \bigcup \Gamma \gamma_k$ as well) that
$$ (T_\alpha \cdot T_\beta) \cdot T_\gamma
= \sum_\sigma m(\alpha, \beta, \gamma ; \sigma) T_\sigma
= T_\alpha \cdot (T_\beta \cdot T_\gamma), \tag{1}$$
where $m(\alpha, \beta, \gamma; \sigma)$ is the number of $(i, j, k)$ such that $\sigma \in \Gamma \alpha_i \beta_j \gamma_k$.
Giving precise definitions of abstract Hecke algebras and Hecke operators for modular forms is usually annoying. This seems much simpler than many other descriptions. But looking more closely, I began to wonder how hard it is to fill in the gaps of showing $(1)$.
Directly expanding symbols shows
$$
(T_\alpha \cdot T_\beta) \cdot T_\gamma
=
\sum_{\tau} m(\alpha, \beta; \tau) T_\tau \cdot T_\gamma
=
\sum_{\tau} \sum_{\sigma} m(\alpha, \beta; \tau) m(\tau, \gamma; \sigma) T_\sigma,
$$
where $m(\alpha, \beta; \tau)$ counts indices $(i, j)$ such that $\tau \in \Gamma \alpha_i \beta_j$, and where for each $\tau$ ranging over a set of representatives $\Gamma \backslash \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q}^+) / \Gamma$, $m(\tau, \gamma; \sigma)$ counts indices $(\ell, k)$ such that $\sigma \in \Gamma \tau_\ell \gamma_k$. (I've implicitly defined $\tau_\ell$ in the expected way).
Showing that this sum is equal to the middle-hand-side of $(1)$ seems very nonobvious to me.

Is there a straightforward way to show $(1)$?


It could be that Bump is simply brushing many details under the rug. To contrast this streamlined presentation with other approaches, I note that Miyake gives what I think of as the standard proof in his book Modular Forms. This proof is based on an isomorphism between $\mathcal{R}$ and the submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[\Gamma \backslash \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})^+]$ that is fixed by right multiplication by $\Gamma$. Now I brush over details, but in short one shows that all the nice properties of $\mathbb{Z}[\Gamma \backslash \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})^+]$ give the relevant nice properties for the Hecke algebra.
This is a fine approach. But I'm looking to streamline presentation without going too handwavy or too mechanical.
